# How JVM -XX:MaxRAM option can be correctly used?

Tags: java, docker, centos, jvm

I run a java application with the following parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JVM_OPTS="-XX:MaxRAM=150m"
export JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -XX:+UseSerialGC"

java $JVM_OPTS -jar application.jar
```

The `htop` shows:

- VIRT=475M
- RES=238M
- SHR=4880
- MEM%=24.1

As I understand it, I need to look at the `RES` parameter. But in this case, it greatly exceeds `-XX:MaxRAM`. Expected that in this case, `OutOfMemoryException` will happen. What am I doing wrong? How to limit the memory of a java application for a container? Am I incorrectly looking at the used process memory?

I want to minimize the used RAM. OS - ​​CentOS 7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting -XX:MaxRam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495429/setting-xxmaxram)

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-XX:MaxRAM` option affects nothing but the [default heap size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54071798/what-is-the-difference-between-xmx-and-maxram-jvm-parameters/54076834#54076834).

Memory used by a Java process (from the OS perspective) includes not only Java heap, but also many other things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624438/3448419) for details.